# Choosing Where to Place Forced Air Wall Heaters

Tags: electrical, hvac, heating, heat, forced-air

I have a small home ~800 sq ft in a mountain climate that gets quite cold in the winters (10s-20s F in the day in the winter). I already have a pellet stove but the other existing heat comes from two baseboard electric heaters that I'm replacing with cadet compak forced air 2000W wall heaters.

This is the existing placement of the baseboard heaters (below the window in the dining room and below the window in the bedroom):

[image]

The easiest thing to do, given that the wires are already there, would be to put the wall heaters right where the old baseboard heaters were. That would look like (where the wall heaters are the red squares):

[image]

[image]

In the bedroom, this means the heater is pointing towards the door (the wall mounted thermostat is also opposite of the heater). Additionally, both heaters would be on outside walls, and thus have no insulation behind them. It appears that Cadet recommends this install when upgrading from baseboard heaters - however im concerned about the lack of insulation in our cold climate. In the bedroom space, I could probably move the heater fairly easily to this wall and place it so that the hallway door when open doesn't block it (note the door to the right of it is actually a slider so wouldn't block it either):

[image]

However, there is an outlet on that wall that I may need to remove, which further complicates things. I'm also not sure of a better option for the dining room space other than the current spot.

Is it worth trying to move the heaters to an interior wall, I'm not really sure what to do here. Any other suggestions on placement given what my area looks like would be great.. Thanks!

Comment: You can get 3-4 times the heat for the same energy from a mini-split heat pump that has an operating temperature at or below your cold range (which is not that cold - mine go to -15°F, so 10-15 above is a cakewalk.)

Comment: Thats a good idea but unfortunately not possible here due to HOA/condo rules. Maybe one day!

Comment: The common recommendation is below or very close to windows, since that is where the coldest air is in the room, due to the windows.  Lack of insulation in the walls is a bigger worry, due to cost of heating, but looks like the only fix is to move if the rules are against it.

Comment: Time for some "I am a Homeowner, I get to play politics with the HOA rules" activity to change the rules. All politics are local, and this is some of the most local politics going.

Comment: @crip659 it sounds like you think it's worth making interior work? Any suggestion on the dining room placement? The only non exterior area there would be on the little partial wall that sticks out next to the kitchen, but then of course the heater will be pointing at the back slider door, so not sure it will be great for circulation

Comment: If you have gas, I would think about a Williams/Empire style wall or floor furnace that uses convection venting.  It doesn't use electricity and will work during a power outage.